# Como puedo insertar una imagen de la web sin necesidad de descargarla? Y como puedo insertar botones en alertas?

Tags: javascript, html, imagen, botón

Como inserto una imagen en mi pagina html sin nescesidad de descargarla y poner su direccion en el codigo?
Y como puedo poner botones en una alerta?

Comment: no se entiende bien que es lo que pretendes hacer, puedes agregar lo que tienes echo y agregar comentarios sobre tu codigo por favor

Comment: @Enzo quiero añadir botones a una alerta, lo de la imagen ignoralo ya lo resolvi

Comment: puedes colocar parte del código que has hecho o bien lo que probaste hacer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const boton = document.getElementById("btn")
boton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  let result = confirm("este es un confirm")
  if(result){
    alert("apretaste aceptar")
  }else{
    alert("apretaste cancelar")
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">
  abrir alert
</button>
```

en mi expreriencia no puedes agregar botones a un alerta, existe una funcion del navegador llamada `confirm(value: string)` esto te puede devolver dos valores, `true` o `false` dependiendo lo que el usuario haga

Comment: gracias me ha servido ahora como hago que esos botones me lleven a una parte de la pagina

Comment: a una parte especifica de la pagina o a otra url?

Comment: a una parte especifica

Comment: ok te recomiendo generar una nueva pregunta con el problema que indicas, puede haber gente que tenga el mismo problema que vos y de querer encontrar una solucion pueda encontrarla facilmente

Comment: no te acostumbres a escribit varias preguntas en una sola, esto no esmuy bien visto en StackOverflow

Comment: jajaja si de hecho ya me dieron ban jajaja, aunque ya lo resolvi, pero no como esperaba :v

Comment: te aconsejo agregar mas detalles sobre los errores que tienes, trata de subir tu codigo con algunos comentarios para que entiendan mas lo que deseas hacer y donde esta tu error, no acostumbres a subir imagenes o capturas de tu problema por que es no se puede copiar y pegar y corregir donde esta el error, y te aconsejo que leas como preguntar asi puedes entender mas de lo que hablo, saludos